# Polyglot-Markup validator

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, polyglot-markup

Is there a free online polyglot-markup validation service that will correctly identify and validate polyglot-markup?

I did find totalvalidator and htmlvalidator but those are (paid) non-web-based solutions.

Comment: Both [Henri Sivonen](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Jan/0059.html) and [Michael Smith](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Jan/0066.html), the maintainers of the W3C and validator.nu validators, have expressed a disinclination to provide a polyglot validator, so the best you're going to get is Jukka's answer.

Comment: On [softwarerecs.se]: [Validator for polyglot HTML5](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/validator-for-polyglot-html5)

Comment: @unor: thanks for pointing me to that new question, let's hope it gets some answers.

Answer (score 8):

Use http://validator.w3.org/nu/ and use “Options” to select first HTML5 (= HTML5 in HTML serialization) parsing mode, then XML parsing mode.

Comment: Is there a difference between the Nu Validator hosted on w3.org and the Living Validator hosted on validator.nu? I imagine that the former validates according to W3C HTML5 whereas the latter validates according to the HTML Living Standard - is my assumption correct?

Comment: @BoltClock - not necessarily. For example `main` inside `article` is not valid in W3C HTML5, but is in HTML Living. However, currently both validators object to it. But it may be that that discrepancy is just too new right now.

Comment: On the other hand, for `hgroup` (invalid in W3C HTML5, valid in HTML Living), the two validators do report in a way that reflects their hosting.