# How to validate angular HTML templates

Tags: angularjs, xml, validation, xhtml, polyglot-markup

I try to write mostly valid polyglot (X)HTML 5 in my angular HTML templates. They look something like this:

```
<div class="some-class">
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="variable" />
  <foo-directive data-ng-if="variable"></foo-directive>
</div>
```

Sometimes I forget closing a tag properly which breaks some browsers. So I would like to include a validator in my toolchain.

The problem is: I do not know of a validator that can handle this case. XML validators typically require a DTD, HTML validators will complain about the angular directives that are used in the code.

Maybe *validator* is the wrong word and I really want a *linter*. The only real thing I want it to do is to check that every opening tag has a matching closing tag. Everything else is a bonus.

Do you know of such a validator?

*NOTE*: I primarily do search for a command line tool that I can integrate with my automated testing. But a webservice might be helpful, too.

Comment: I am using [htmlhint](http://htmlhint.com/) (through [Grunt](https://github.com/yaniswang/grunt-htmlhint) - but it makes no difference, there is also a CLI). I only use the `tag-pair` (ensure that tags are closed) and `attr-no-duplication` options.

Comment: Works great! I would except that as an answer if you create it.

Comment: related: [Polyglot-Markup validator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16281471/588079) and [Validator for polyglot HTML5](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/validator-for-polyglot-html5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since [htmlhint](http://htmlhint.com/) is an option, you can use it as described [here](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/Usage) from command line (of course you will have to `npm install` it first and make sure your `PATH` contains `node_modules/.bin`):

```
htmlhint test.html
```

To test for specific options:

```
htmlhint -r tag-pair,attr-no-duplication test.html
```

Or if the options are in a configuration file:

```
htmlhint -c config-file test.html
```

I use the following options with Angular:

- `tag-pair`: make sure tags are closed properly
- `attr-no-duplication`: no duplicate attributes in an element

Comment: how do you make `htmllint` ignore custom directives and attributes?

Comment: It doesn't care about custom attributes/elements, at least in the online validator on their [front page](http://htmlhint.com/).

Comment: true, I noticed the same thing later

Comment: If you use atom you can add the package `linter-htmlhint`:
https://atom.io/packages/linter-htmlhint

Answer (score -2):

The [`html-angular-validate`](https://github.com/nikestep/html-angular-validate) project is what I use, and I think it's perfect for this.  It uses the W3C HTML validation service, and it basically just ignores errors about know angular stuff (like properties that begin with `ng-*` that are normally invalid HTML)

I run it via gulp using [`gulp-html-angular-validate`](https://github.com/ewu02/gulp-html-angular-validate)

You will have to configure it to know about your custom element and attribute directives, which can become a bit of a pain if you are always adding new ones... however once you've done this it works quite well and has saved my team many times by finding simple typos and common errors!